# Laravel 4:Can the migration file be reused?

Tags: laravel-4

Can the migration file be reused?
In my project,I use the migration to make the database table.
And then I sent to my friend. 
But he can't use the migration command to get these tables;
Always 'Nothing to migrate',So,May I ask how you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nothing to migrate` appears only if Laravel detected that  migration done already. Now question is, how Laravel detect migration already done?

if you go to your database (using PhpMyadmin or Sequel pro), you will see there is a table called `migrations`. Laravel store all migration information to the `migrations` table. **Do not share this table with your friend.** . If you share the table already, ask your friend to empty the table.

Than run the migration again.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I found the problem is he has one of the tables which I sent him few days ago.Drop it then migrate is fine.